# Express generator of kernel in terms of basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, group-homomorphism

I have a pretty basic question. Let's consider the linear transformation $\varphi = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ between the $2$-dimensional vector spaces $A$ and $B$ which are each isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, thus consider the map $$\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$$ and let's call it $\phi$ and let's assume we have a basis $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}  =\langle a,b\rangle$.

The kernel $\ker \phi $ is given by $$ \ker \phi =\left\{ \lambda\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$$ thus $\dim \ker \phi = 1$.

My question is: why can i express the kernel with respect to the generators $a,b$ by $$\ker \phi = \langle a-b\rangle?$$

I remember seeing this a few times but apparently there's something i am missing and i'd love to know why the last expression is valid. Clearly any element of the kernel is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$, but why is $\langle a-b\rangle$ generating $\ker \phi$?

Or rather, what's the relation between the solution $(1 -1)^\top$ of $\ker \phi$ and $a-b$ precisely?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $a = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right]$ and $b = \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$.

Comment: Yes, but why can i express $a$ and $b$ as such? Is it because they are considered to be the canonical basis vectors and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ are just the coordinate vectors of $a$ and $b$ with respect to $\langle a,b\rangle$ ?

Comment: The reason i am confused is because $a$ and $b$ could for example just be $n$-cycles in a homology group $H_n(X)$ and i have issues seeing them as vectors as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ has a standard basis consisting of the vectors $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$. If you just have a group that happens to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ you need to pick a basis in order to exhibit that isomorphism, and once you do you can write elements of that group in coordinates.

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly the point where i was not too sure whether my intuition is correct. Thank you very much! Would you mind elaborating what you mean precisely by exhibiting that isomorphism by picking a basis?

Comment: I mean if $A$ is a free abelian group of rank $n$, there's a natural bijection between bases of $A$ and isomorphisms $\phi : \mathbb{Z}^n \to A$, where the natural bijection sends such an isomorphism $\phi$ to the basis $\phi(e_1, \dots e_n)$, where $e_i$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. The same result is true for free modules over any ring, e.g. for vector spaces. Homology groups can be free but they are (usually) not *canonically* free; picking an isomorphism to some $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is equivalent to picking a basis of the homology group.

Comment: Thank you vm @QiaochuYuan, highly appreciating your help.

Comment: You're very welcome! This can be tricky stuff.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But i am sincerely happy about your answer, because i learned something i obviously didn't know and not something i might have maybe forgotten about linear algebra. I'm actually pretty excited.